# Nesting IF in Windows Bat file

Tags: script, batch-file

I am having some difficulty in understanding how the Nested IF works in windows .bat script. What I wish to achieve is as follows. I shall be passing two parameters to a bat file

IF first parameter = 0 AND if Second parameter = 0 run proc1

IF first parameter = 0 AND Second not 0 run proc2

IF first parameter is not 0 run proc 3

The skeleton of the code I have written so far is

```
@echo off

IF %1% == 0 (
    IF %2% == 0 ( goto proc1
    ) ELSE ( goto proc2
)
  ELSE ( goto proc3
)

:proc1
echo in Proc1 0 0
pause
exit
:proc2
echo in Proc2 0 N0
pause
exit
:proc3
echo in Proc3 N0  0
pause
exit
```

The issue is that  it’s working fine for the first two conditions but when first parameter is non zero is still falls thru proc1 whereas expected is proc3. What am I missing here? The script does not give any error except if the parameters are omitted in the first place.

Comment: To the close voters - batch files are on-topic on [su]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not actually sure you need ELSE, let alone a nested IF, for your use case:

```
@echo off

IF NOT "%1%"=="0" (
    goto proc3
)
IF "%2%"=="0" ( 
    goto proc1
) 

goto proc2 

:proc1
echo in Proc1 0 0
pause
exit
:proc2
echo in Proc2 0 N0
pause
exit
:proc3
echo in Proc3 N0  0
pause
exit
```

If for some reason you really do want to nest your IFs, you're missing a bracket:

Your batch:

> ```
> IF %1% == 0 (
>     IF %2% == 0 ( goto proc1
>     ) ELSE ( goto proc2
> )
> ***MISSING )***  ELSE ( goto proc3
> )
> ```

Batch that should work:

```
IF "%1%" == "0" (
    IF "%2%" == "0" ( 
    goto proc1
    ) ELSE ( 
    goto proc2
    )
) ELSE ( 
    goto proc3
)
```

Comment: I would use `EQU` instead of `==` as OP is comparing numbers not strings (see my answer).

Comment: +1 for using `if` ... `else`

Answer (score 0):

#### What am I missing here?

The `==` comparison operator always results in a **string** comparison.

You need to use `EQU` instead to perform a **numerical** comparison.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off

IF NOT %1% EQU 0 (
    goto proc3
)
IF %2% EQU 0 ( 
    goto proc1
) 

goto proc2 

:proc1
echo in Proc1 0 0
pause
goto :exit
:proc2
echo in Proc2 0 N0
pause
goto :exit
:proc3
echo in Proc3 N0  0
pause
:exit
```

Notes:

- Some `goto :exits`s have been added to terminate the procs instead of `exit` which terminates the enclosing `cmd` shell.

Example output:

```
F:\test>example 0 0
in Proc1 0 0
Press any key to continue . . .

F:\test>example 0 1
in Proc2 0 N0
Press any key to continue . . .

F:\test>example 1 0
in Proc3 N0  0
Press any key to continue . . .
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.

Comment: Thank you Jonno & DavidPostill for your answers. You both have shown me a more streamlined version of my code. Now I also understand that I was missing a closing bracket in my original script!